# Why the value read from properties file in python doesn't work

Tags: python

I am brand new to Python. I have some python script which is accessed by other project to read some data from this python script.

Past:
If suppose I need to provide the version information for the other project from this python script, I was having a class variable which was hard coded and it was working fine till now.

Now:
I wanted to change the way of providing the version information so I choose to read the properties file instead of hard coding. I have added these line in my script

previously it was just this line

```
class Myclass
    version = '1.2'
```

Now I changed it to

```
 class Myclass
    config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
    config.read('version.properties')
    version = config.get('global', 'version')
    print version
```

my version.properties file looks like

```
[global]
version= 1.2
```

when I run this python file to print the version, it is clearly printing in the console. But when this variable is being accessed by that other project the version read from the properties file is not being read (Hard coded value works just fine).

What could be the difference? Why is the value read from properties file is not reflecting?

Comment: This code will only find the `version.properties` file if it's in the current directory.  Does the other project run from a different directory?

Comment: Yes the other project that access this script is in the different directory but the properties file is the same dir as the script is which is what expected right?

Comment: No.  Your code will look in the current working directory, which will be whatever directory the other project was executed from.

Comment: So you mean to say the prop file should be in that projects dir instead of scripts dir?

Comment: The prop file should be wherever you want it to be; there is no clear answer.  Some developers prefer not to have config files and code files in the same directory.  If you want it to be in the same directory as your class code, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `version.properties` file will be in the same directory as your code, you can use this:

```
import os

config.read(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'version.properties'))
```

Comment: Great! It worked. Thank you so much, saved me lot of time.

Comment: Could you please explain why is this addition of os path when it is able to access the properties file in the same dir?

Comment: This code tells Python to look for  the `version.properties` file _in the same directory as the code file itself_, instead of the current working directory.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes. I got it. Thanks @John